# Accessing the latter elements of a python list with several duplicated elements

Tags: python, string, list, chatbot

Taking the fictional list **A** and giving this keywords for a scan (**id, messageid, firstname, type, text**) and given that the following items (**those that are marked in bold**) on the list are relevant, while others are not. **A =**

> ['ok', 'true', 'result', 'updateid', '230999144', 'message', 'messageid', '26', 'from', 'id', '250313842', 'firstname', 'John', 'lastname', 'Doe', 'chat', 'id', '250313842', 'firstname', 'John', 'lastname', 'Doe', 'type', 'private', 'date', '2490213676', 'text', '/start', 'entities', 'type', 'botcommand', 'offset', '0', 'length', '6', 'updateid', '230999145', 'message', **'messageid'**, **'27'**, 'from', **'id'**, **'250313842'**, 'firstname', 'John', 'lastname', 'Doe', 'chat', 'id', '250313842', **'firstname'**, **'John'**, **'lastname'**, **'Doe'**, **'type'**, **'private'**, 'date', '2490213690', **'text'**, **'Damn'**, **'it'**, **'feels'**, **'good'**, **'to'**, **'be'**, **'a'**, **'gangsta'**]

We can see that there's *a lot* of redundancy on this list, but the truth is that this repetition can happen N times, not just two times, as in this example. The latter results are always the ones that are relevant in the 'scan'. How to best access them? I would like not to use multiple 'index' in order to keep the code as efficient as possible.

Keep in mind that the desired output is something like this:
`messageid: 27`
`userid: 250313842`
`username: John Doe`
`usertext: "Damn it feels good to be a gangsta"`

The list in question comes from a chatbot's **https push gate** and it's pushed as a text string, it's original form would be:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 230999144,
      "message": {
        "from": {
          "id": 250313842,
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        },
        "entities": [
          {
            "length": 6,
            "type": "bot_command",
            "offset": 0
          }
        ],
        "text": "/start",
        "date": 2490213676,
        "message_id": 26,
        "chat": {
          "id": 250313842,
          "type": "private",
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 230999145,
      "message": {
        "date": 2490213690,
        "chat": {
          "id": 250313842,
          "type": "private",
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        },
        "message_id": 27,
        "text": "Damn it feels good to be a gangsta",
        "from": {
          "id": 250313842,
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok": true
}
```

I thank you in advance for the help in solving this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desired output?

Comment: My gut tells me that whatever you are doing before you got this list can be done better, to get a data structure that is more manageable.

Comment: @Julien yeah, totally. How are you suppose to know how many elements to take after "text"?

Comment: I presume you're doing the `.split()` though, right? And it comes as just text?

Comment: This looks that JSON read by a drunk parser.

Comment: Indeed, it comes as a text string, I use `.translate()` to replace the **:** and **,** characters into spaces in order to properly `.split()`

Comment: That's useful information that you don't want to get rid of. Can you post the original text?

Comment: I have added the original string, as per your request @Julien

Comment: Yup, it's JSON.

Comment: Althought the original string is JSON using `json.loads()` in order to transform it into a python object does not give me a data structure that is more manageable than the given list. Any idea of how I can better process this data @Julien

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After the **text** All elements are to be taken. This is done by `while i<(len(list)):`

Comment: I reject the notion that under any reasonable measure that this list of strings is more manageable than the parsed data structure.

Comment: @CaioFleury How could you possibly think that this list of strings is more manageable than the Python object that results from deserializing the JSON???

Comment: The code that was being used was unpacking the JSON converted dict into a list, that is why this list was mora manageable. Guess I should had posted the code as well. At any rate, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you have no control over what code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Since the original text is JSON, you can use `json` to parse it into a dictionary:

```
import json

data = json.loads(your_json_string)
```

...and now you can access all the data like you would any dictionary / data structure.

```
>>> data["result"][-1]["message"]["text"]
u'Damn it feels good to be a gangsta'
```

Comment: I would use `data['result'][-1]` since that is what the OP requested... it illustrates how much simpler it is to work with this data structure than a list of strings..